# Multidimensional list in Thymeleaf (Java) - List<List<Object>>

Tags: list, multidimensional-array, thymeleaf

Have anyone of you any suggestion, how to iterate through a multidimensional list in Thymeleaf?

My multidimensional list looks as follow:

```
@Override
public List<List<PreferredZone>> findZonesByPosition(List<Position> positionList) {

        List <PreferredZone> prefZone = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<PreferredZone>> listPrefZone = new ArrayList<>();
        long positionId = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < positionList.size(); i++) {

            positionId = positionList.get(i).getPositionId();
            prefZone = prefZoneDAO.findFilteredZone(positionId);

            listPrefZone.add(prefZone);
        }

    return listPrefZone;
}
```

In my controller as attribute:

```
List<List<PreferredZone>> prefZoneList = prefZoneService.findZonesByPosition(positionList);
    model.addAllAttributes(prefZoneList);
```

Finally I try to iterate this two dimensional list in a HTML table:

```html
<table th:each="prefList :#{prefZoneList}" class="table table-striped display hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ISO</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Ausschluss</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- Loop für die Daten -->
 
  <tr th:each="row, iterState :${prefList}" class="clickable-row">
    <td th:text="${row[__${iterState.index}__]}.zoneIso"></td>
    <td th:text="${row[__${iterState.index}__]}.zoneName"></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <input type="checkbox" th:value="${${row[__${iterState.index}__]}.zoneId}" id="zone" class="checkbox-round" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It doesn't work however. I don't have any other idea how to solve this.
I have to have a multidimensional list, because I have got a table with multiple records and each record contains a button to open a modal window. Each of this windows contains either a HTML table where I have to display the records.

Have you got any suggestion for me?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?  What happens if you change `${row[__${iterState.index}__]}.zoneIso` to just `${row.zoneIso}`?

Comment: When I do it as you mention, then I get a follow error:

**org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'zoneIso' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String'**

Comment: When I try with:
**<td th:text="${row}"></td>**
the HTML rendered looks as follow: **??prefZoneList_de??**

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in `#{prefZoneList}` and (as noted in comments) in using `iterState.index`

Try it:

```
    <table th:each="prefList : ${prefZoneList}" class="table table-striped display hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ISO</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Ausschluss</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tr th:each="row : ${prefList}" class="clickable-row">
        <td th:text="${row.zoneIso}"></td>
        <td th:text="${row.zoneName}"></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <input type="checkbox" th:value="${row.zoneId}" id="zone" class="checkbox-round" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Syntax `#{...}` - a message Expressions

`iterState.index` is the current iteration index, starting with 0, using like `${prefList[__${iterState.index}__].element}` where `element` - filed in `prefList`.

Comment: Elisabeth, thank you for the prompt response! To be honest, I didn't verify your suggestion because I solved my challenge with JSON, what was the better solution in my case anyway. I talked however with few friends and they confirmed your answer. I assume it would work.